# Omitting articles in headlines and captions

Tags: articles, headlinese

As far as I know, when the space for the text is limited (for example, in case of a newspaper headline), some articles can be omitted. What I'm trying to understand is **which** articles should and **which** articles should **not** be omitted.

Here is the Emacs reference card: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf. From the "Files" section:

> Save a file back to disk: `C-x C-s`

There is no article before the word "disk", and I'm sure it is omitted for brevity and not because of any other reason. On the other hand, the article before the word "file" is not omitted.

Why the second article is omitted and the first one is not?

Comment: Your supposition is wrong. This is not a headline or caption, and "save to disk" is a standard phrase.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Isn't it should be "a disk" or "the disk" instead? We don't use "disk" in abstract sense here, so using zero article doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: But this is an abstract sense. It's not specifying any particular disk.